# ajax is not going to controller and data is not updating

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, insert-update

**My Ajax script is not going to controller and data is not uploading.**

Script is:

```
$("#update").click(function(event) {
/* Act on the event */

var chango = $("#update_form").serialize();
alert(chango);
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>home/update_profile",
    data:{id:id}
},
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        list_user();
    });
event.preventDefault();
});
```

and my controller is:

```
public function update_profile()
{
    try {

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("fname", "First Name", 'required|alpha');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("lname", "Last Name", 'required|alpha');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("mobile", "Mobile", 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("dob", "Date of Birth", 'required');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules("gender", "Gender", 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()){
        $this->load->model("user");

        $data=array(
              'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
              'lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
              'mobile' => $this->input->post('mobile'),
              'dob' => $this->input->post('dob'),
              'gender' => $this->input->post('gender')
            );
        if ($this->input->post("update")) {
            $this->user->update_data($data, $this->input->post("id"));
            redirect(base_url() . "home/list_user");
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
    } 
    catch(Exception $e) {

    }
    $this->load->view('middlepage/update_profile.php');
}
public function update()
{
    $user_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->load->model("user");
    $data["user_data"] = $this->user->fetch_single_data($user_id);
    $data["fetch_data"] = $this->user->fetch_data1();
    $this->load->view("middlepage/update_profile", $data);
}
```

And my model is:

```
public function fetch_single_data($id)
    {
        $this->db->where("id", $id);
        $query = $this->db->get("user");
        return $query;
    }
    public function update_data($data, $id)
    {
        $this->db->where("id", $id);
        return $this->db->update("user", $data);
    }
```

And my view is:

```
<form method="post" id="update_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="true">
                                        <?php if(isset($user_data))
                                        {
                                            foreach ($user_data->result() as $row) {
                                        ?>
                                        <div class="form-group valid-form">
                                            <h4>First Name:</h4>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" value="<?php echo $row->fname ; ?>">
                                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("fname");?></span>
                                        </div><br>

                                        <div class="form-group valid-form">
                                            <h4>Last Name:</h4>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" value="<?php echo $row->lname ; ?>">
                                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("lname");?></span>
                                        </div><br>

                                        <div class="form-group valid-form">
                                            <h4>Mobile:</h4>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" value="<?php echo $row->mobile ; ?>">
                                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("mobile");?></span>
                                        </div><br>

                                        <div class="form-group valid-form">
                                            <h4>Date of Birth:</h4>
                                            <input type="date" class="form-control" min="1984-01-01" max="2005-12-31" id="dob" name="dob" value="<?php echo $row->dob ; ?>">
                                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("dob");?></span>
                                        </div><br>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <h4>Gender</h4>
                                            <div class="radio">
                                                <label>
                                                  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"<?php if($row->gender == 'male') echo "checked"; ?>><span style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 15px;">Male</span>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="radio">
                                                <label>
                                                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female"<?php if($row->gender == 'female') echo "checked"; ?>><span style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 15px;">Female</span>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("gender");?></span>
                                        </div><br>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id ?>">
                                            <input type="submit" name="update" id="update" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        </div>
                                        <?php
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </form>
```

i can't update data in database and it is not going to list table 
ajax function is not working and not going to codeigniter's controller

while is try this type of similar code to submit it is work perfectly

Comment: You are not passing other parameters other then `id` in ajax call.

Comment: means i have to pass all parameters

Comment: Yes. You need to pass like `data: $("#update_form").serialize()`

Comment: i tried but it's is still not working

Comment: `data:{
      fname:<?php echo $row->fname ;?>,
      lname:<?php echo $row->lname ;?>,
      mobile:<?php echo $row->mobile ;?>,
      dob:<?php echo $row->dob ;?>,
      gender:<?php echo $row->gender ;?>
     }`

Comment: and i put your code and it is stuck in that page not refreshing and not going another page

Comment: replace `function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        list_user();
    });` 

with

 `success:  function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        list_user();
    });`

Comment: no bro it is still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From where you get id which you pass as data in id field

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>home/update_profile",
    data:{id:id} <--
},
```

Comment: As @Dhananjay Kyada suggested you need to pass all the data which you need to modify and than get that data in PHP